# Specific amount of data from database in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

How can I take specific amount of data from database ? I am working with Yii2.
What I have tried so far is:

```
$model = new \app\models\Post();

for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $post = $model::find()->orderBy(["post_id" => SORT_DESC])->one();
    $contetnt = $post['content'];

    echo "<div>" . $contetnt . "</div>";
}
```

With the for loop it shows me 3 times the content of the last post ofcourse, but how should I reconstruct it to work?
I took a look at many posts but did not found the answer, or maybe I did not understand how to make it work!
The idea is just to show last 3 posts on the home page of the site.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show last 3 posts:

```
$lastPosts = Post::find()->orderBy("post_id DESC")->limit(3)->all();
foreach ($lastPosts as $post) {
    // ...
}
```

Read this: [Active Record Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html)
and this: [Active Record methods](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#methods).

Answer (score 0):

```
    $model = new \app\models\Post();
    $posts = $model::find()->orderBy(["post_id" => SORT_DESC])->limit(3)->all();
    foreach ($posts as $post){
        $contetnt = $post['content'];
        echo "<div>" . $contetnt . "</div>";
    }
```

**[note:]** if you use ActiveQuery::one() or yii\db\Query::one() , you need to add `limit(1)` ,because yii2 does not do that for you automatically, so if you use `->orderBy(["post_id" => SORT_DESC])` ,MySQL will fetch all table columns to your web server and yii2 just retrieve one of them. This may lead request status of 504 gateway timeout error if the table has large records.

Comment: Good to know! Thank you a lot!